# Adding further style after stylesheet

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to add further styling after setting a view to a style-class?

I have some elements which each have the same structure. I want to set an individual background color to each of these elements.

For example:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    gridItem: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 100,
        width: '50%',
    }
})
```

and in my render:

```
<View style={styles.gridItem} />
<View style={styles.gridItem} />
<View style={styles.gridItem} />
```

What I want to achieve is that each of these Views have an individual color. So to summarize, I want to add further styling in form of

```
style={{backgroundColor: ''}}
```

after setting the style class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object assign or spread might do the work ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)):

```
<View style={{...styles.gridItem, backgroundColor: '#f00'}} />
<View style={{...styles.gridItem, backgroundColor: '#0f0'}} />
<View style={{...styles.gridItem, backgroundColor: '#00f'}} />
```